# Не могу понять как ограничить поле в туду листе на js

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пож. никак не получается устранить данную ошибку в туду листе, прописывал уже и   `newTask.style.maxWidth = 100 + '%';` но, бесполезно. Как можно устранить? Сделать чтоб он корректно отображался и для задач с большим кол-вом информации, был перенос.

https://codepen.io/igor-solodownik/pen/zYZKmBR

```
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo__list');
const myForm = document.querySelector('.todo__form');
const inputTask = document.querySelector('.form__input');
const priorityButton = document.querySelector('.form__btn-priority');
const noteEmptyList = document.querySelector('.noteForEmptyList');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let newTask = document.createElement('li');
  newTask.textContent = inputTask.value;
  todoList.append(newTask);
  inputTask.value = '';

  let buttonDeleteTask = document.createElement('div');
  buttonDeleteTask.textContent = 'Удалить';
  buttonDeleteTask.classList.add('btn-del');
  newTask.append(buttonDeleteTask);

  if (priorityButton.classList.contains('is-important')) {
    newTask.classList.add('is-important')
  }
  showsNoteForm();
});

myForm.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('btn-del')) {
    event.target.parentNode.remove();
    showsNoteForm();
  }
});

function showsNoteForm() {
  if (todoList.childElementCount > 0) {
    noteEmptyList.classList.add('no-show');
  } else {
    noteEmptyList.classList.remove('no-show');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 46 && todoList.lastChild) {
    todoList.removeChild(todoList.lastChild);
    showsNoteForm();
  }
});

priorityButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.classList.toggle('is-important');
  if (this.classList.contains('is-important')) {
    this.textContent = 'Важная задача';
  } else {
    this.textContent = 'Обычная задача';
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 17) {
    priorityButton.classList.toggle('is-important');
  }
  if (priorityButton.classList.contains('is-important')) {
    priorityButton.textContent = 'Важная задача';
  } else {
    priorityButton.textContent = 'Обычная задача';
  }
});
```

Comment: Это из-за того, что нет пробелов в тексте.

Comment: li { word-wrap: anywhere;}

Comment: А зачем вы кнопку абсолютом сделали? Задайте flex родителю, чтобы всё на своих местах было.

Comment: li { word-wrap: anywhere;} Спасибо) Первый раз правда слышу за это свойство. Правда сейчас нюанс в другом. Сделал флексом по Вашему совету, но отображение такое: https://codepen.io/igor-solodownik/pen/zYZKmBR фото прикрепил

Comment: а flex-wrap то зачем сделали?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;  
  word-break: break-word;
}

.btn-del {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid rgb(102, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    word-break: normal;
}


li::before {
    counter-increment: myCounter;
    content: counter(myCounter);
    color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #18C8FF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А, разве word-break: по умолчанию не normal идет?

Comment: Он от li наследовался и текст в кнопке переносился. Так что для кнопки переопределил

Comment: Понял) Большое спасибо) Разобрался!)

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот фото после того как добавил родителю флекс